# html file in python template engine

Tags: html, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

if have this code but i dont know why its repeating twice please help me.

```
<h2>New Person</h2>

<form method="post" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    Gender: <select name="Gender">
        <option value="Male" selected>Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    Full name: <input type="text" name="Full_name">
    <br>
    Height: <input type="text" name="Height">
    <br>
    Age: <input type="text" name="Age">
    <br>

    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form>
```

[my output in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMqda.jpg)

Comment: `{{ form.as_p }}` renders the form, and then you render the form manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{{ form.as_p }}` *renders* the form. So it makes no sense to use both `{{ form.as_p }}` and then write the form manually. We can work with:

```
<form method="post" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

or you can decide to manually render the form, but not both, since then these will both render the form items.

Answer (score 0):

You already imported a form from forms.py using `{{ form.as_p }}` ,  you just have to wrap it around a FORM tag with a submit button at the bottom.

```
`{{ form.as_p }}`
          Submit
```